# Usage of attributes in VC15

Tags: c++, c++11, attributes, standards

According to this paper http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2761.pdf class and methods attributes should be declared as follows

```
 struct B {
     virtual void f [[ final ]] () {};
 };
```

This example is from paragraph 11.3. But compiling this code gives me a warning

```
 warning C5030: attribute 'final' is not recognized
```

But if I write

```
struct B {
     virtual void f () final {};
};
```

compilation proceeds without warning and everything works just fine.

I'm using visual studio 15 with toolset v140.

My question is, am i improperly using the first form from standard or VC15 is simply broken in this feature?
And is second example of 'final' usage visual specific or it works on gcc too?

Comment: There is no VC15. As you pointed out, the toolset and therefore the compiler is named VC14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is old document, `final` is `the virt-specifier`, second code is correct.
N4296 10.3/4

> If a virtual function f in some class B is marked with the
>   virt-specifier final and in a class D derived from B a function D::f
>   overrides B::f, the program is ill-formed.

```
struct B {
virtual void f() const final;
};
struct D : B {
void f() const; // error: D::f attempts to override final B::f
};
```